# Обновление OpenSSL в Android Stuido

Tags: android, android-studio, openssl

Проблема: **Google** отказывается публиковать приложение в **Google.Play**.
Причина: `The vulnerabilities were fixed in OpenSSL versions beginning with 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za`.

Используется **Android Studio 1.5**, **ОС Windows 7**.
Все пакеты обновлены до последних версий.

Подскажите, как обновить **OpenSSL**?
Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Код приложения:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class DBAction {
    DBAction() {
    }
    public static String getData(String id, String passkey, String command, String param){
        String response = "";
        try {
            String q = "https://myserver.com";
            HostnameVerifier TRUST_ALL_CERTIFICATES = new HostnameVerifier()
            {
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            SSLContext Cur_SSL_Context = null;
            try
            {
                Cur_SSL_Context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                Cur_SSL_Context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509_Trust_Manager() }, new SecureRandom());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(TRUST_ALL_CERTIFICATES);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(Cur_SSL_Context.getSocketFactory());
            URL url = new URL(q);
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection= (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            String urlParameters =DBHelper.PARAM_POST_ID+"="+id+ "&" + DBHelper.PARAM_POST_PASSKEY + "="+passkey;
            if (param != null)
            {
                urlParameters += "&";
                urlParameters += DBHelper.PARAM_POST_PARAM;
                urlParameters += "=";
                urlParameters = param;
            }

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            int responseCode = httpsURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            response = stringBuffer.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Exception = " + e);

        }
        return response;
    }

    private static class X509_Trust_Manager implements X509TrustManager
    {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {}
        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {}
        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
        {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

**UPD**: рекомендованная Гуглом команда 
'$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"' даёт пустой результат

**UPD2**: libs - пуста

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Какие библиотеки подключены? Проблема не в Android Studio. Вероятно какая-то библиотека статически линкуется со старой версией OpenSSL.

Comment: А какой версии build tools? да и вообще какие версии сдк использованы? Покажите весь build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

В случае необходимости обновления нативных библиотек есть два пути:

1. Найти готовые `.so` библиотеки и подключать их в проект в качестве NDK-зависимостей; затем явно в коде вызывать `System.loadLibrary("yourlib");` (не забывать ловить исключения, которые эта функция может выбросить)
2. Брать исходники библиотек, отдельно собирать эти библиотеки, затем переходить к п.1

**ВАЖНО**:

Нужно помнить, что есть такой параметр как `ABI` ([подробнее тут](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html)). Контролируется он при `gradle` сборке параметром `abiFilter`. Для всех архитектур должна быть собрана своя библиотека, которая должна лежать в соответствующей папке.